# How To Select One row in Table and Echo In PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table for my products and I select them in index page and it works true but I want to click one of the products (at index) and then go to product detail page and get selected product data and echo that I will get my row id at product detail page but i don't know how to select a row by that id and then show that data

The first line is working true and I get my product id from the index page 
but I don't know how to write a select code and I want to show my selected data in article tag and my table name is "products" and my fields are name, type, img, price, des, id

```
<?php

$myid = $_GET['pid'];

require_once 'setting.php';
$dbc = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

$query = "SELECT * FROM products where id = $myid";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

echo "
    <article>
        <img src = \"{$products['img']}\"><br>
        <a>name: </a>{$products['type']} <br>
        <a>title: </a>
        <a style='color:white;'>{$product['name']}</a> <br>
        <a>price: </a>{$products['price']} <br>
        <a>descrition: </a>{$products['des']} <br>
    </article>";

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

I know my code is totally not true so that's an example to show my Target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fetch the result row as an associative array using **mysqli_fetch_assoc(result);**

Try this :

```
 <?php   

                $myid = $_GET['pid'];


                require_once 'setting.php';
                $dbc = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
                mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

                $query = "SELECT * FROM products where id = $myid";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

                  $products = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


                echo "
                       <article>                                
                                <a>name: </a> $products['type'] <br>
                                <a>title: </a>
                                <a style='color:white;'>$product['name']</a> <br>
                                <a>price: </a>$products['price'] <br>
                                <a>descrition: </a>$products['des'] <br>
                       </article>";

                mysqli_close($dbc);
            ?

>
```

Comment: @SaeedSheikh add iterators in it if you want to fetch multiple rows currently it will fetch the only 1st row